# Blender 2.83 limit track

Tags: modeling

[image: animation of the drawer]

[Video (Google drive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C1ypwESykQOyl2UWGQzP3cU3T7yyNnny/view?usp=sharing)

I couldn't upload a video on the website so I uploaded a video to Google drive. Anyway, I've created a drawer and gave it a '*Limit Distance*' constraint. It works well in the front direction, but when I try to pull it back, it goes to the back.
How can I fix this? I want to do this one way (in the front direction). This should not go backwards.

I'm sorry for my bad English. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, what's your question ?

Comment: oh sorry, how can i fix this. I want to do this one way(in front way) this should not go backwards.

Comment: _Limit Distance_ as the name says limits the distance to a target. Which means, you can move the object in any arbitrary direction (spehrical around it), as long as it's stays within the set distance.

Comment: oh all right i got it thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is limit location, not limit distance.

[image]

Just set min and max of 2 axis to 0. So you cannot move it on that axis.

And set min and max value of your "moveable" axis to 2 values (min should be lower than max).

then you get:

[image]

Comment: YES, thats what I'm looking for. I'm appreciate for your reply and your time.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @Burak Other than shown in the screenshot you should rather set _Owner_ to _Local Space_ instead of _World Space_. If your drawer is parented to the cupboard and your moving the cupboard around, the drawer will stay in its place (or move only those 2 m in Y direction) because the location is limited to _World Space_.